# Automatically extend a Sheets formula for each new Google Form response

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, formulas

I have created a Google Form that logs new customers. Since the business is mostly run on cellphones during the day, I wanted to make it as mobile-friendly as possible.

One of the form response items is a phone number, and to create a call option that will dial when accessed on a mobile device, I can use the formula:
`=HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/"&E3, "Call "&C3)`

This works great, but I have to manually extend it each time a new response is submitted. Is it possible to tweak the formula so that every new entry will have that formula applied to it, increasing the E and C row references by one?
E.g. my next entry would update the formula to call E4 and display the name from C4.

The other option is to do that manually after every entry but I'm hoping I can avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=arrayformula(if(len(C3:C), HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/"&E3:E, "Call "&C3:C), text(,)))
```